# Difference between style.xml and theme.xml android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

Hey I'm trying to change the background of my action bar but I'm not quiet sure I understand the structure of the style files. So basically I have style.xml which is to pass on some elements a desired style. Then I've Theme.xml which is to have a group of styles in it, correct ? How do you link the two in other words how do I tell the theme I want the specified style in it ? I can't manage to change the background of the action bar so here is my code:

style.xml:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/color_lightBlue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

 </style>

</resources>
```

and wtf is v11/style ?

Comment: v11/style is for android devices using Android API version 11 or higher. If you want styles specific to later versions, you can use that folder structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you put the attributes in `styles.xml` or `theme.xml`, they have the same effect finally if you apply the theme to your app or activity. In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, in order to let the theme have the effect you want, you should apply your customized theme like following to your app.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Yep, it's pretty much a naming convention as far as those files go, it has something to do with the new lollipop changes to styling where they have moved to using 'theme' rather than 'style'.

Comment: hum I thought styke was for single elements like textviews and theme was to group up those single element. That is wrong ? I've to put everything in one or the other file but not both then ?

Comment: @CedricVandenBosch Yes, you can think like that. A group of attributes applied to a single view is usually called style and a group of attributes applied to activity or app is usually called theme. [Reference here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to get more information.